# SQL SERVER - Select next row value upto 5 characters and then replace first character with new one

Tags: sql, sql-server, apache-spark-sql

I have a situation where i want to read next value of the same column and concat it upto five characters and store it in different column but i am not able to do so
Please see below for better visualization.

Here's the input

```
------------------------------
|      ID      |   word      |
------------------------------
|       1      |      M      |
|       2      |      V      |
|       3      |      V      |
|       4      |      M      |
|       5      |      V      |
|       6      |      M      |
|       7      |      V      |
|       8      |      M      |
|       9      |      V      |
|       10     |      V      |
------------------------------
```

Desired output:

```
-------------------------------------------- 
|      ID      |   word      |  expected   |
--------------------------------------------
|       1      |      M      |      M      |
|       2      |      V      |      MV     |
|       3      |      V      |      MVV    |
|       4      |      M      |      MVVM   |
|       5      |      V      |      MVVMV  |
|       6      |      M      |      VVMVM  |
|       7      |      V      |      VMVMV  |
|       8      |      M      |      MVMVM  |
|       9      |      V      |      VMVMV  |
|       10     |      V      |      MVMVV  |
--------------------------------------------
```

In this expected column after appending the 5th character when it goes to 6th row and tries to append, it will first remove first character 'M' from 'MVVMV' (5th row) and then append 'M' from 6th row at the end of 'MVVMV' which will be 'VVMVM'

i hope you get this logic as i have tried many ways to achieve this but no luck

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `lag()` and `concat()`:

```
select t.*,
       concat(lag(word, 4) over (order by id),
              lag(word, 3) over (order by id),
              lag(word, 2) over (order by id),
              lag(word, 1) over (order by id),
              word
             ) as concat_5
from t;
```

Unfortunately, SQL Server does not (yet) support `STRING_AGG()` as a window function.  If it did, you could use:

```
select t.*,
       string_agg(word) within group (order by id) over
            (order by id rows between 4 preceding and current row) as concat_5
from t;
```

Comment: i tried this but it gets the value in next row it should get me on the same row http://sqlfiddle.com/#!18/3743fb/1

Comment: @abhishek . . . I fixed it.